# Has Many Through, but include property from middle table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using the example from the Laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```
projects
    id - integer
    name - string
 
environments
    id - integer
    project_id - integer
    name - string
 
deployments
    id - integer
    environment_id - integer
    commit_hash - string
```

```
class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the deployments for the project.
     */
    public function deployments(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Deployment::class, Environment::class);
    }
}
```

How would I be able to include `name` from the `environments` table as part of the `deployments` object?

i.e.:

```
$projects = Projects::with('deployments')
    ->get();
```

And each `deployment` object would look something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "environment_id": 1,
    "commit_hash": "123",
    "name": "name_from_environments_table_here"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue of how you would like to represent the data with the keys you mentioned can be done using `public function toArray()` like so:

```
class Deployment extends Model
{
    public function toArray(): array {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'environment_id' => $this->environment_id,
            'commit_hash' => $this->commit_hash,
            'name' => $this->environment->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

However, if you have multiple use cases for the deployment object you can also consider using an `EloquentResource` as a Data Transfer Object.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Resources;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
 
class DeploymentResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'environment_id' => $this->environment_id,
            'commit_hash' => $this->commit_hash,
            'name' => $this->environment->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Just take note that you will need to map the Eloquent Models of `Deployment` objects to Resource Objects see the Laravel Documentation of [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) for more on this.

Comment: Just suggestion for variable name (array key) to be `environment_name`.

Comment: Agreed, I would also use that naming convention as well, but I was trying to maintain the structure as OP provided it, in case external resources need to consume it as is.